# unrecognised configuration section System.IdentityModel

Tags: c#, asp.net, adfs

I've been following an example from MSDN for ADFS (how to build claims-aware asp.net forms application using WIF https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh987037.aspx) but getting the above mentioned error. My target framework is .NET 4.5. Any clues why I'm getting this error?

thanks,
Maulik

Comment: I am also getting this issue.